# Unlock cellphone when receiving a call

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm developing an app that can make calls using Xamarin. I have done everything, but I have an issue.

I'm unable to open the app after the cellphone enters lock mode. When the cellphone is locked and I receive a call, I'm able to hear the sound but the screen is black. If I unlock the phone I can able to see the incoming call screen, so the problem is when the cellphone is in lock mode.

How can I open the lock programmatically in Xamarin Android?

I have tried with this code:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)contextA.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.AcquireCausesWakeup, "0");
wl.Acquire();
//Code goes here
wl.Release();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a special permission in your AndroidManifest

Comment: may I know what permission need to be set?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html android.permission.WAKE_LOCK